# why submit on key enter not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a login form where if the input sn on focus and then you press enter it will prompt errors asking you to fill out the fields. But if you fill out both fields, no error comes out and even when you enter the correct credentials and then press enter. nothing happens. the form just gets reset. It works fine if I click the button though.

I am using semantic ui as front-end framework and using its form validation for the errors. Is it because of semantic?

[here](http://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/form.html) the link for semantic ui form validation's documentation

Here is my form

```
<form id="login" class="ui large form" method="post" action="">
    <div class="ui stacked secondary  segment">
        <div class="field">
            <div class="ui left icon input">
                <i class="user icon"></i>
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Nama Pengguna">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <div class="ui left icon input">
                <i class="lock icon"></i>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Kata laluan">
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="btn-login" value="Log-masuk" class="ui fluid large teal submit button">
    </div>

    <div class="ui error message"></div>
</form>
```

and the javascript for it is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ui.form').form({
        fields: {
            username: {
                identifier: 'username',
                rules: [{
                    type: 'empty',
                    prompt: 'Sila masukkan Nama Pengguna'
                }]
            },
            password: {
                identifier: 'password',
                rules: [{
                    type: 'empty',
                    prompt: 'Sila masukkan Kata Laluan'
                }]
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You're not actually doing anything with the form? `action=""`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney im posting the form to same page

Comment: Im wondering what the problem is. The form gets reset because you post it to the same page.

Comment: And does the page handle the post? If the form is resetting, sounds like the page may be refreshing?

Comment: @Craicerjack oh i see and it works fine if the button is clicked. im at lost of what to do. stuck with this probs for few days.

Comment: Sorry what is the problem?

Comment: @Blunderfest if the post is submitted user will be logged in. if user is logged in the page will redirect them to dashboard.so u can't access the login page if you are logged in.

Comment: @Craicerjack the form didnt get submitted when i press enter key but it is submitted if i click manually on the button

Comment: It did. It got submitted to itself.

Comment: @Craicerjack the page suppose to prompt an error that says wrong username/password if wrong one is submitted

Comment: @Craicerjack if i remove the javascript and press enter. the page says wrong password. but nothing happens when i place the javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the form has 2 options.
When you hit enter the form submits and when you click the button, your Javascript runs.
You dont want it to submit, you want to trigger the attached JavaScript so
remove the form `method` and the form `action`
This is a rule in general, you let the form submit handle the submission, or you let the JavaScript handle it.

As you can see from the [semantic ui docs](http://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/form.html) the form doesnt have a method or action

```
<div class="ui horizontal divider">or</div>
<form class="ui form segment">
  <div class="two fields">
    <div class="field">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inline field">
    <div class="ui checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="terms">
      <label>I agree to the terms and conditions</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui blue submit button">Submit</div>
  <div class="ui error message"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: oh i see.. but how will it determines where to submit without method or action?

Comment: you were right though, i fix it and let the form validation activate on form submit. it works now thanks ! but removing method and action meand i have to add the method amd action in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I prefer to use the default submit button in a form, and not add extra javascript to get a form submit working.

I also had this code:

```
<div class="ui fluid large blue submit button">
   <p>Register</p>
</div>
```

But when you replace this with this:

```
<button type="submit" class="blue fluid large ui button">Register</button>
```

You have the same layout, and the default submit button is working.

of course you still need the form action and method:

```
<form action="/register/process-form" method="POST" class="ui large form">
```

by the way, i use jade template rendering, in jade above codes are:

```
    form.ui.large.form(action="/register/process-form" method="POST")
      div.ui.stacked.segment
       div.field
         div.ui.left.icon.input
           i.user.icon
           input(type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail adres")
         div.ui.fluid.large.blue.submit.button
           p Register
         button.blue.fluid.large.ui.button(type="submit") Register
```

Note: i showed both buttons in the jade code to show the difference, you need to use the bottom one.